# Understanding the return values of LOGEST in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am doing line fitting in Excel and I endded up with an exponential decay. The displayed equation of the fitted line is

y=723880e^-4E-04x

I want to have the coefficients calculated in cells so I used the LOGEST function. The base "b" as return value is correct with 723880 and the other value "a" is 0,99964514. It is correct if i do

(a-1) or
ln(a).

Could someone explain to me why this is the case and what function is this LOGEST really describing? It isn't the one explained in the HELP section, the y=bm^x.

Thanks for everyone's help in advance.

Comment: `LOGEST` is returning the value of `b`, not the value of the coefficient of `e`. In order for it to match what you see on the chart to the return of LOGEST (using `ln(b)` to get the coefficient), you may need to increase the precision of the trendline equation on the graph.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/statistical-functions-logest